# How to identify that the step is RunTestCase in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have following Structure:

*Each single functionality is broken down in Reusable script and reusing all in the Main Suite.*

```
TestCase 1:
    1. Login as Normal Customer (This is calling login test case from Reusable script)
    2. Extract Session from STEP 1
    3. Add diner card  (This is calling add card test case from Reusable script)
    4. View Added Card (This is calling view test case from Reusable script)
    5. etc..
```

Now Each test case in Reusable script returns a property that r_result (Passed or Failed)

Now I wanted to check each run test case and see the property r_result is Passed or Failed. If It is failed, I need to check where the First Failed occurs (in `RunTestCase`) and report that error.

Is It possible to isolate ONLY RunTestCase steps in each Test case and use it in closure to get the results of each RunTestCase results?

Comment: Is that you want to find the test steps of "RunTestCase" type across the test cases of test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script which can fetch the list of matching test steps across the soapui project.

Please follow the in-line comments.

`result` variable has all the list of test steps of required type. The you can leverage and do the needful using this data.

**Script:**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlRunTestCaseTestStep

//To identify lookup test step is not this step
def currentStepMap = [ suite : context.testCase.testSuite.name, case  : context.testCase.name, step  : context.currentStep.name ]
//Type of step to look for
def stepTypes = [WsdlRunTestCaseTestStep]
//To hold the final result
def result = []

//Find the test step details of matching step
def getMatchingMap = { suite, kase, step ->  
    def tempMap = [suite : suite.name, case : kase.name, step: step.name]   
    def isNotMatching = currentStepMap != tempMap ? true : false
    if (isNotMatching &&(stepTypes.any{step in it}) ) {
        tempMap
    } else { [:] }
}

def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project

//Loop thru the project and find the matching maps and list them
project.testSuiteList.each { suite ->
    suite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
        kase.testStepList.each { step ->
            def tempResult = getMatchingMap(suite, kase, step)
            if (tempResult) {
                result << tempResult    
            }
        }
    }   
}

if (result) {
    log.info "Matching details: ${result} "
} else {
    log.info "No matching steps"
}
```

Comment: @ChanGan, glad to know that it helped.